# why I am getting this notice in my website

Tags: php

I m getting this error notice on my website Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /home/wouogkqedr4z/public_html/wp-content/plugins/kingcomposer/includes/kc.front.php on line 566
try{

```
        /*
        *   Decode JSON object
        */      
        $screens = json_decode( str_replace( '`', '"', $code ), true );

        /*
        *   Sort screens
        */
```

line566-    if (is_array( $screens['kc-css']))
{

```
            kc_screen_sort ($screens['kc-css']);

            foreach ($screens['kc-css'] as $screen => $groups)
            {
            
                $css_array = array(); 
                $css_code_itm = '';
```

Comment: `$screens` is null.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+%22Trying+to+access+array+offset+on+value+of+type+null%22

Answer (score 1):

Before accessing an index, try checking that the `$screens` is indeed an array using the `is_array()` function.

```
if ( is_array( $screens ) && is_array(  $screens['kc-css'] )
```

Answer (score 0):

You get errors when you don't have values in the array. So when you use array try to check it first.

```
if (!empty($screens['kc-css']))
```